# pandas add a column with only one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This sounds a bit weird, but I think that's exactly what I needed now:

I got several pandas dataframes that contains columns with float numbers, for example:

```
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

Now I want to add a column, with only one row, and the value is equal to the average of column 'a', in this case, is 3.0. So the new dataframe will looks like this:

```
   a  b  c  average
0  0  1  2  3.0
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

And all the rows below are empty.

I've tried things like `df['average'] = np.mean(df['a'])` but that give me a whole column of 3.0. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you cant bro. this is a dataframe. what you can do, is to set up all the values behind the first row as `NaNs`

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Can do the fake way to add empty strings

Comment: great  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can do something like:

```
df['average'] = [np.mean(df['a'])]+['']*(len(df)-1)
```

Comment: What I want for empty is just like something does not print out, as you did

Answer (score 7):

Assign a series, this is cleaner.

```
df['average'] = pd.Series(df['a'].mean(), index=df.index[[0]])
```

Or, even better, assign with `loc`:

```
df.loc[df.index[0], 'average'] = df['a'].mean().item()
```

Filling NaNs is straightforward, you can do

```
df['average'] = df['average'].fillna('')
df
   a  b  c average
0  0  1  2       3
1  3  4  5        
2  6  7  8
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(0,1,2), (3,4,5), (6,7,8)],
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(df)

   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8

df['average'] = ''
df['average'][0] = df['a'].mean()
print(df)

   a  b  c average
0  0  1  2       3
1  3  4  5        
2  6  7  8
```